# Grails Asset Pipeline: Access Full Application Stack

Tags: grails, stack, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to extend the Asset Pipeline plugin with support for assets that contain GSP style commands (ie: ${variable}, , etc.).  This is fairly easily done by using the GroovyPagesTemplateEngine to process the files.  Everything works fine when I'm running in debug mode, however, things fall apart when the same code runs during the WAR file creation process.

I've tracked down the problem to the fact that during the WAR file creation process the Asset Pipeline plugin doesn't make the full Grails Application stack available to the code doing the asset processing (this fact is documented in the Asset Pipeline docs).  So I'm wondering if I can make the full Application stack available myself to my own code.  Obviously there would be a big performance hit (which is why the Asset Pipeline plugin doesn't do this), but it's worth it for the flexibility that is gained.